# How to execute Windows System() command from C:\Windows\System32 folder?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, command

I have a batch file "install.bat" stored in location "

> c:\Users\abc\xyz

".
I want to execute this batch file in administrative mode from

> C:\Windows\System32

folder using a System() API. Can anyone kindly lemme know how do I achieve this VC++ programatically.

My code snippet::

```
int ret = System("c:\Users\abc\xyz\install.bat");
```

If I give this command,  batch file is of course executing from "c:\Users\abc\xyz" folder. But I want to run this batch file from System32 folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to put a `cd` command as the first line of your .bat file. You could change the working directory of the calling process, but that's using a hammer to crack a nut.

If you move away from the `system` function you can call `CreateProcess`. That allows you to specify all the gory details you need when creating a new process. You need to run the command interpreter (find that by reading the `COMSPEC` environment variable). You can specify the working directory for the new process as one of the parameters to `CreateProcess`.

`CreateProcess` is rather hard to call though. And it won't help you with requesting elevation to admin rights. Instead you can use `ShellExecute`. Call that passing `"runas"` for the verb, which will result in elevation.

```
ShellExecute(0, "runas", "c:\\Users\\abc\\xyz\\install.bat", NULL, 
    "C:\\Windows\\System32", SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: Beaten to it by a few seconds :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Something like the following

```
ShellExecute(hwnd, "runas", "c:\\Users\\abc\\xyz\\install.bat", NULL, "c:\\windows\\system", SW_SHOWNORMAL );
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using System(), you can just `cd` to the location containing the **.bat** file and just invoke the batch file